# TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().django2.2.2

Tags: python, django, typeerror, callable

I am trying to make my first app with in `urls.py` the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', 'blogs.views.home', name='home'),
    path('admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

`

I get this error `TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()`.

When I do not use quotations, like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', blogs.views.home, name='home'),
    path('admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

I get the following error `NameError: name 'blogs' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You need to *import* the modules then, like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
import blogs.views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', blogs.views.home, name='home'),
    path('admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Since hier you use an *identifier*, and that needs to be in scope. If you use a string literal, Django will resolve this by using the `importlib`.